# Access: Syntax error in JOIN operation

Tags: sql, join, ms-access-2010, external

I'm trying to finish the query below but I keep getting the error message:

> "Syntax error in JOIN operation".

```
SELECT myExternalTable1.INCIDENT_ID AS INCIDENT_NR, 
First(myExternalTable1.PARENTITEM) AS [COMPANY], 
First(myExternalTable1.LOGGEDDATE) AS [LOGGED_DATE], 
First(myExternalTable1.STATUS) AS [STATUS], 
First(myExternalTable1.PRIORITY) AS [PRIORITY], 
First(myExternalTable1.CATEGORY) AS [COMPLEXITY], 
First(myExternalTable1.USERGROUP) AS [GROUP], 
First(myExternalTable1.SPECIALISTID) AS [SPECIALIST], 
First(myExternalTable1.MODULE) AS [CATEGORY], 
Last(myExternalTable1.ActionDate) AS [ACTIONDATE], 
First(myExternalTable1.Description) AS [DESCRIPTION], 
iif([STATUS]=""Closed"" Or [STATUS]=""Cancelled"" Or [STATUS]=""Resolved"", DateDiff(""d"",LOGGED_DATE,ACTIONDATE), DateDiff(""d"",LOGGED_DATE,Date())) AS [DAYS_OPEN], 
myExternalTable2.responseachieved AS [SLA_STATUS]
FROM ((myExternalTable1 IN 'K:\SOME_FOLDER\SOME_FOLDER\SOMEFOLDER\myExternalDB1.accdb') 
LEFT JOIN (myExternalTable2 IN 'K:\SOME_FOLDER\SOME_FOLDER\SOMEFOLDER\myExternalDB2.accdb') 
ON myExternalTable2.id = myExternalTable1.INCIDENT_ID) 
WHERE (LOGGED_DATE>#12/31/2013#)
GROUP BY INCIDENT_NR 
ORDER BY LOGGED_DATE;
```

I tried to rename the tables and the file paths to keep these secret while still preserving the syntax that was used in them. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Remove these `()` around: `FROM (myExternalTable1 IN 'K:\SOME_FOLDER\SOME_FOLDER\SOMEFOLDER\myExternalDB1.accdb') 
LEFT JOIN (myExternalTable2 IN 'K:\SOME_FOLDER\SOME_FOLDER\SOMEFOLDER\myExternalDB2.accdb') 
ON myExternalTable2.id = myExternalTable1.INCIDENT_ID`

Comment: Thank you for your response. If I understand you correctly I should remove the `(` after `FROM` and the `)` after `INCIDENT_ID` but doing this does not fix the problem. I still get Syntax error in JOIN operation

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT met.INCIDENT_ID AS INCIDENT_NR, 
First(met.PARENTITEM) AS [COMPANY], 
First(met.LOGGEDDATE) AS [LOGGED_DATE], 
First(met.STATUS) AS [STATUS], 
First(met.PRIORITY) AS [PRIORITY], 
First(met.CATEGORY) AS [COMPLEXITY], 
First(met.USERGROUP) AS [GROUP], 
First(met.SPECIALISTID) AS [SPECIALIST], 
First(met.MODULE) AS [CATEGORY], 
Last(met.ActionDate) AS [ACTIONDATE], 
First(met.Description) AS [DESCRIPTION], 
iif([STATUS]=""Closed"" Or [STATUS]=""Cancelled"" Or [STATUS]=""Resolved"", DateDiff(""d"",LOGGED_DATE,ACTIONDATE), DateDiff(""d"",LOGGED_DATE,Date())) AS [DAYS_OPEN], 
met2.responseachieved AS [SLA_STATUS]
FROM [;database=K:\SOME_FOLDER\SOME_FOLDER\SOMEFOLDER\myExternalDB1.accdb].[myExternalTable1] AS met
LEFT JOIN [;database=K:\SOME_FOLDER\SOME_FOLDER\SOMEFOLDER\myExternalDB2.accdb].[myExternalTable2] AS met2 ON met2.id = met.INCIDENT_ID
WHERE (LOGGED_DATE>#12/31/2013#)
GROUP BY INCIDENT_NR 
ORDER BY LOGGED_DATE;
```

Comment: what do the `met` and `met2` parts do? I'm sorry, I'm still a bit green when it comes to sql, also, doing this causes access to give me a "Syntax error in FROM clause" error

Comment: met and met2 are the aliases he's applying to the tables which makes it easier to reference them. Maybe wrap them back in brackets like before but keep the aliases as above (Keep the brackets removed that Juergen d suggested too)

Comment: I have now put brackets around `(myExternalTable1 IN 'K:\SOME_FOLDER\SOME_FOLDER\SOMEFOLDER\myExternalDB1.accdb' met)` and `(myExternalTable2 IN 'K:\SOME_FOLDER\SOME_FOLDER\SOMEFOLDER\myExternalDB2.accdb' met2)` but I still get syntax error in JOIN operation

Comment: also tried placing the closing brackets before the aliases

Comment: Do you get results if you just do `SELECT * FROM myExternalTable1 IN 'K:\SOME_FOLDER\SOME_FOLDER\SOMEFOLDER\myExternalDB1.accdb'`

Comment: When I use that sql statement I do get results